# FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1, android remote database registration

Tags: java, php, android, mysql

I've been trying to build a registration system for android using php and mysql but i have come across an error that i am unable to fix. Could someone have a look at it and see if they spot anything that i don't please.

register code:

```
public class RegisterActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private EditText user, pass;
    private Button  mRegister;
         // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
        // JSON parser class
        JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

    private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://95.85.22.140/webservice/register.php";

    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";
        @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

            user = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.registerUsername);
            pass = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.registerPassword);

            mRegister = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnRegisterDetails);

            mRegister.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
        @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    new CreateUser().execute();
    }
        class CreateUser extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
             /**
             * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
             * */
            boolean failure = false;
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                pDialog = new ProgressDialog(RegisterActivity.this);
                pDialog.setMessage("Creating User...");
                pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                pDialog.setCancelable(true);
                pDialog.show();
            }
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 // Check for success tag
                int success;
                String username = user.getText().toString();
                String password = pass.getText().toString();
                try {
                    // Building Parameters
                    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
                    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
                    Log.d("request!", "starting");
                    //Posting user data to script
                    JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(LOGIN_URL, "POST", params);
                    // full json response
                    Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());
                    // json success element
                    success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                    if (success == 1) {
                        Log.d("User Created!", json.toString());
                        finish();
                        return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
                    }else{
                        Log.d("Login Failure!", json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE));
                        return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }
            /**
             * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
             * **/
            protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
                // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
                pDialog.dismiss();
                if (file_url != null){
                    Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, file_url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }   
}
```

register.php

```
<?php

require("config.inc.php");

// If posted data is not empty
if(!empty($_POST))
{
    // If the username or password submition is empty
    if(empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['password']))
    {
        // Create a JSON response
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Please enter a username and a password.";
        die(json_encode($response));
    }
    // Check to see if there is already a user with the username
    $query = "SELECT 1 FROM registration WHERE username = :user";
    // update the empty :user variable
    $query_params = array(':user' => $_POST['username']);
    // run query against database
    try
    {
        $stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
    }
    catch (PDOException $ex)
    {
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Database Error1. Please Try Again!";
        die(json_encode($response));
    }
    //return username data if already in use
    $row = $stmt->fetch();

    if($row)
    {
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "I'm sorry, this username is already in use";
        die(json_encode($response));
    }
    // Query to create a user
    $query = "INSERT INTO registration (username, password) VALUES (:user, :pass)";
    // Update variables with actual data
    $query_params = array(':user' => $_POST['username'], ':pass' => $_POST['password']);
    try
    {
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
 }
    catch(PDOException $ex)
    {
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Database Errror2. Please Try Again!";
        die(json_encode($response));
    }
    // By this point, user has been added
    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["message"] = "User Successfully Added!";
    echo json_encode($response);
}
else{
?>
    <h1>Register</h1>
    <form action="register.php" method="post">
        Username:<br />
        <input type = "text" name="username" value ="" />
        <br /><br />
        Password:<br />
        <input type="password" name="password" value="" />
        <br /><br />
        <input type="submit" value="Register New User" />
    </form>
    <?php
}
?>
```

logcat error:

```
04-05 13:35:53.441: W/dalvikvm(8373): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x418b3898)
04-05 13:35:53.471: E/AndroidRuntime(8373): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
04-05 13:35:53.471: E/AndroidRuntime(8373): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
04-05 13:35:53.471: E/AndroidRuntime(8373):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
```

Any help would be great thanks

Comment: try removing the  finish(); on doinbackground()

Comment: try below code and let me know whether it is working or not.

Comment: i tried changing the code and i also tried removing finish(); but still got the same error.

Comment: I see you have `Log.d` - Messages there. What is the last of them comming through?

Comment: The only message that comes through is "starting" so i'm assuming there may be a problem with the HttpRequest.

Comment: Have you tried catching the RuntimeException and print its stacktrace? In the code above you catch JSONException, only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I too had similar issue and i solved by changing it's **onPostExecute** method. just give a try to below code.

```
protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            if (pDialog != null) {
                if (pDialog.isShowing()) {
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
        }
```